# How to interpret the coefficients obtained from lme4, which has two co-variants in level 2?

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, nested-data, growth-model

I am doing a longitudinal study investigating how Y changed across time, with two time-invariant covariates at level two (between-person), one is  `Gender` and another one is `OnAge`. So I tried to formulate a conditional growth model via lme4, and if I was correct, the equation should be like this:

Level 1: Yti=b1i+b2i Time+uti

Level 2: b1i=β01+β11Genderi+β21OnAgei+d1i
b2i=β02+β12Genderi+β22OnAgei+d2i

Composite: Yti=(β01+β11Genderi+β21OnAgei+d1i)+(β02+β12Genderi+β22OnAgei+d2i)*Time+ uti

Accordingly, the formula for lme4 should be `lmer(Y~Time+Gender+OnAge+Gender*Time+OnAge+Time+(Time|id))`

---

The question here is how should I interpret the obtained Level-2 coefficients of `Gender`, `Gender*Time`, `OnAge`, and `OnAge*Time`? I suppose the interpretations for them should be very different from unconditional growth model.